# How to make label to appear instead of name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, node.js

My form should contain `key=>value` pair, where `key`  should be `label`of the form and `value` should be details entered by user,

My issue is getting `name` of the field instead of `label`,

Expected `output`:

```
         ENTER YOUR AGE:25
```

but i m getting output  like this:

```
           name-preview : 25;
```

How can it be achieved for expected `output`?

```js
var result = [];

$('div label').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var label = $this.text();
  //console.log(label);

  value = $this.siblings().attr('value');
  //console.log(value);

  result.push({
    label: label,
    value: value
  });
});


console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="uploaddata.php" method="POST">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text-1483332101835-preview" class="fb-text-label">enter your age:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" value="25" id="mobNum">
  </div>
```

>

how can i make for this `elements`:https://jsfiddle.net/ktgmtwd7/1/

Comment: It is not clear what your expected output is. Can you please elaborate? You can get the name using `name = $this.siblings().attr('name');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this—when you change the the input value then the results array will auto update:

```js
var result = [];
var input;
$('div label').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var label = $this.text();
  input = $this.next();
  result.push({
    label: label,
    value: input.val()
  });
  console.log(result);
  $this.next().on('keyup', function() {
   result = [];
   result.push({
       label: label,
       value: input.val()
   });
    console.clear()
    console.log(result);
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="uploaddata.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text-1483332101835-preview" class="fb-text-label">enter your age:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" value="25" id="mobNum">
  </div>
</form>

<h3></h3>
```